# Facebook upload photo+applink

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-share, applinks

I'm working on an ios-only app that the user creates a unique pattern with, and then shares this pattern (image) on Facebook via upload. What I want is that when people click on this image in the feed, it should open my app. This functionality can be done via AppLink.

The problem is that whichever method I try, I can't get both requirements to be met. If I use the photo share API, then while adding just the image works, as soon as I add an applink (or any link), the image disappears and the standard applink box appears. If I use the graph API to upload the image, the image gets uploaded but the link is ignored. I *can* put the link as initialText, but that leads to two issues: 1) Any text not physically typed by the user is not allowed by Facebook sharing, and 2) it only renders as the regular link itself, not like an applink (but problem #1 is the big one - I can't be doing something Facebook doesn't allow).

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do - adding a clickable user-generated image to a feed, clicking on which opens my app?

I should add here that the images don't have a web URL, they don't exist on the web - they are directly uploaded from the mobile and appear in the facebook feed of the user.

I've tried this with the Javascript SDK as well as iOS. Any help, irrespective of platform, is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The way I see it, using the graph API to do a photo upload will probably not work, since I need the publish_actions permission for it and that I'll never get since I need to put in a non-user entered link. So, I feel that the solution to the problem is somewhere in Sharing a custom photo (via upload, not via URL), with a custom link.

Comment: _“So, I feel that the solution to the problem is somewhere in Sharing a custom photo (via upload, not via URL), with a custom link”_ - that would still have the same problem - that your app is not allowed to specify the URL, the user would have to type it in manually as part of their photo caption. AFAIK the Mobile Hosting API for App Links does not support to specify an image, so I think the only proper solution to this would be to share external URLs, that have the image set as thumbnail, and include the app link meta data. (Of course that needs HTTP(S) image URLs.)

Comment: thanks @CBroe, that's what I was afraid of. I was trying to keep it 'serverless', but I guess I'll need to upload the image on a server and then share a link to it. Would you happen to know if I need to keep the image around after Facebook has crawled it, or can I safely delete it?